# Xcode 8.2 - Why is my TextView vertically centering text when I don't want it to?

Tags: xcode, uitextview

I am using Xcode 8.2, developing for iOS 10.

I have a tab controller with three child view controllers.  Two of these view controllers are fine when it comes to text views.  However, one of these view controllers is showing strange behavior when it comes to a `TextView`.  The text seems to be vertically aligned when it shouldn't be.  The Alignment property on the Attributes Inspector has `---` selected (the far right one).  Selecting other ones does nothing to it.  I've tried removing the `TextView` and dragging in a new one and it still exhibits the same behavior.  No amount of backspacing or trying to new text does anything.

Text is vertically centered but clicking on it as if to edit it shows that it's fine.

I've even tried removing the entire view controller, creating a new one and linking it with my tab view controller and that doesn't work either.

[image][image][image]

**EDIT**:

I've attached my attribute inspector here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

[image]

Uncheck that checkbox (in the containing view controller).